# Utilizar Ajax para carregar opções de vários selects após escolher uma opção

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Ps.: Esta pergunta não é a mesma já feita em outro tópico. Esta envolve Ajax. Acho engraçado um monte de gente marcando como duplicada sem sequer ler o cerne de cada questão ou se propor a responder qualquer uma das duas.

Tenho um formulário onde eu gostaria de escolher determinada opção em um `<select>` e carregar, via ajax, opções relacionadas vindas do banco de dados em vários outros `<select>`(Tipo aquela solução de selecionar o Estado, no outro select, bairro, cidade, etc). Gostaria que fosse possível categorizar as mesmas para que uma mesma opção pudesse pertencer a várias categorias (como se uma cidade pudesse pertencer à vários estados e um bairro também)

É algo MUITO parecido com isso aqui (http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/a807b00bb785cea30160aaa7c8e458ac/), mas adaptado para funcionar com `<select>` ao invés de Checkbox.

Ah, eu utilizo o plugin jquery select2

Comment: Você já fez esta pergunta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184340

Comment: E aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184091

Comment: Amigo, esta é um pouco diferente e envolve Ajax. As outras perguntas também, mesmo que semelhantes, não foram respondidas a ponto de resolver o problema.

Comment: Murilo, as outras perguntas devem ter sido atendidas da forma em que você perguntou, mas pode não ter resolvido o seu problema pois você não mencionou estes detalhes anteriormente.

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184340/criar-um-filtro-com-m%C3%BAltiplas-categorias-utilizando-um-select/184368#184368

Neste topico voce solicitou um jsfiddle e uma explicação, ele foi feito, mas também não respondeu a mesma. 
Neste mesmo tópico você não mencionou esta necessidade de agora.